# VSCode fails to run python with this error: Error: Session cannot generate requests

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, garmin

I am trying to run python in vscode and it has been working for a few hours but it suddenly stopped running and now whenever i run it i get this error:

Error: Session cannot generate requests
at w.executeCodeCell

I am connecting to a garmin account where i pull the sleeping data and trying to plot it on a graph which worked but now it has stopped working and giving me the above error.

How would i fix this?

Comment: Could you please provide the picture of the error. It should be helpful if we can know the stack of the problem and where prompt it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to restart the Kernel.

Everytime I am facing this issue myself, it was because the kernel was loosing the connection and had to be restarted.

Answer (score 2):

You might get this error because your script has run `exit()`. Remove that and rerun, and you should be fine.

Comment: this is why i hate computers

Answer (score 0):

Exit the VS Code and reopen it.

It worked for me!