# How can I solve this problem? (vs code error)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import check_util.checker as checker
from IPython.display import clear_output
from PIL import Image

import os
import time
import re
from glob import glob
import shutil
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow import keras

print('tensorflow version: {}'.format(tf.__version__))
print('GPU available: {}'.format(tf.test.is_gpu_available()))
```

> Error: Session cannot generate requests Error: Session cannot generate
> requests at w.executeCodeCell
> (c:\Users\ooche.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1054968649\out\client\extension.js:90:320068)
> at w.execute
> (c:\Users\ooche.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1054968649\out\client\extension.js:90:319389)
> at w.start
> (c:\Users\ooche.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1054968649\out\client\extension.js:90:315205)
> at runMicrotasks () at processTicksAndRejections
> (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) at async
> t.CellExecutionQueue.executeQueuedCells
> (c:\Users\ooche.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1054968649\out\client\extension.js:90:329732)
> at async t.CellExecutionQueue.start
> (c:\Users\ooche.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1054968649\out\client\extension.js:90:329272)

I think this problem has something to do with kernel.

But I can't find a solution, even though I've already reinstalled and restarted.

Please help me solve this problem.

I'm using Python 3.7.10, Tensorflow 2.3

Comment: Check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68259660/vscode-fails-to-run-python-with-this-error-error-session-cannot-generate-reque May be it helps

Comment: @OnurBaştürk I tried but it's not working for me.. thanks answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try again by restarting the **VS code** or by changing the **jupyter** virtual environment (Change kernel for the notebook) while executing this code in **VS code**.

(I tried the same code as mentioned above in **VS code** using `python 3.7.10` and `tensorflow=2.3` and it executed successfully)

Please check this output:

```
tensorflow version: 2.3.0
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6944\127915523.py:16: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
GPU available: False
```